# Xcode archive issue

Tags: xcode

error reading dependency file '/Users/ali.basha/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TimeSheet-bwqqkabfrmsuhgajoglwwtbqvkdv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/TimeSheetDev/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/TimeSheet.build/Release-iphoneos/TimeSheetDev.build/Objects-normal/arm64/TimeSheetDev-master.d': missing ':' following rule at position 25031816 (in target 'TimeSheetDev' from project 'TimeSheet')

Comment: Can you guys please help on this

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting derived data, here are the steps

1. Go to Xcode menu -> Preferences
2. Go to Locations -> Look for Derived data location
3. Go to that specific folder and remove derived data